# Where to find the win32api module for Python?

Tags: python, winapi

Many Python scripts and examples contain `import win32api`. However, from the name it is not directly clear what this library is or which library it is part of. What is the `win32api` module and where can it be found / how can it be installed?

*(NB: This also applies to the `win32con` and `win32file` modules.)*

Comment: Ironically, googling "python win32api" now leads to this page.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

'pywin32' is its canonical name.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/

Comment: No longer on sourceforge: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32

Answer (score 181):

<strike>There is a a new option as well: get it via pip!  There is a package [pypiwin32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32) with wheels available, so you can just install with: `pip install pypiwin32`!</strike>

Edit: Per comment from @movermeyer, the main project now publishes wheels at [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/), and so can be installed with `pip install pywin32`

Comment: For those like me getting "Access denied" errors while installing, try ``python -m pip install pypiwin32`` as suggested by [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172719/pip-install-access-denied-on-windows/31183559).

Comment: As of 2017-11-11, the project [moved to GitHub](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) and publishes wheels at `pywin32`, which should probably be considered the new correct answer.

Comment: Does it make a difference when you install with pip as opposed to through your typical point and click IDE ui?

Answer (score 8):

I've found that UC Irvine has a great collection of python modules, pywin32 (win32api) being one of many listed there.  I'm not sure how they do with keeping up with the latest versions of these modules but it hasn't let me down yet.

UC Irvine Python Extension Repository - http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs

pywin32 module - http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32