# How to find / import the win32security in python?

Tags: python, winapi

I am writing an application in Python, the code was already there. I tried to run the code, but I got this error.

```
import win32security
ImportError: No module named win32security

import win32api
ImportError: No module named win32api
```

I have installed Python in my local set up and it's working fine I think. I open cmd prompt and typed "python",
I get this response

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

So Python is installed. What changes do I need to do to make my code work? Is there any package named win32api, or win32security I have to install separately to get it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably [PyWin32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32)

I m not quite sure because I use linux sys but I believe this is what you are looking for.

It is third-party python module/extension and thats why you can't `import` it with standard python distribution.

Comment: I did `pip install pywin32` but still got `No module named 'win32security' `

Comment: You also need to execute `python Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install`, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48506623/542235

Answer (score -4):

You need to install this module. Open the windows cmd and execute:

> > pip install win32security
> >
> > pip install win32api

You need to conexión to internet.

Comment: probably brother detected