# Python 3.6 install win32api?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to install the win32api module for python 3.6 or do I have to change my version of python?
Everytime I try to install it using pip I get the following error:

```
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement win32api (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for win32api
```

Comment: go on here https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20220/

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Information provided by @Gord

Since September 2019 `pywin32` should be installed via PyPI which ensures that the latest version (currently version 304) is installed. This is done via the `pip` command

```
pip install pywin32
```

If you wish to get an older version the sourceforge link below would probably have the desired version, if not you can use the command, where `xxx` is the version you require, e.g. 300

```
pip install pywin32==xxx
```

This differs to the `pip` command in another comment and in an old edit of this answer in that `pypiwin32` installs an outdated version (namely 223)

Browsing the docs I see no reason for these commands to not work for all `python3.x` versions, I am unsure on `python2.7` and below so you would have to try them and if they do not work then the solutions below will work.

---

**Probably now undesirable solutions but certainly still valid as of September 2019**

There is no version of specific version of`win32api`. You have to get the `pywin32`module which currently **cannot** be installed via `pip`. It is only available from this link at the moment.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20220/

The install does not take long and it pretty much all done for you. Just make sure to get the right version of it depending on your `python` version :)

---

Also it can be installed from this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases) as provided in comments by @Heath

Comment: Well, my project gets all the requirements through a requirements.txt which the IDE picks up and installs everything. Everything except pywin32, because it isn't on pip.

Comment: Update, September 2019: `pywin32` is now available [from PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) and installs the latest version (currently version 224). `pypiwin32` currently installs an older version (223).

Comment: @GordThompson Deleted my last comment as it was NLN, is there anything I have missed in the update? if not feel free to flag this comment the same when you have seen it.

Comment: The one point that I think is worth making is to use `python -mpip` _or `py -3.n -mpip` if you have more than one version of python installed (where n is the version of python3)_.

Answer (score 31):

Take a look at this answer:
[ImportError: no module named win32api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343774/importerror-no-module-named-win32api)

You can use

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

Comment: is there any documentation for this api?

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywin32'

Comment: @VincentAlex is that when you are trying to install it, or when you are trying to import into your app?

Comment: On importing to python3 3.8 on win7