# Error after adding Django channels to installed_apps in settings file

Tags: django, django-channels

I am just trying out django channels so I created a virtual environment and installed django, drf and channels. It threw error asking for visual c++ build tools which got resolved after installing it. Then I created a channels project and an app. Then just for testing I added a sample model as below and registered it with the admin. It compiled well and also I was able to see the model in the admin page.

My Model Calss

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class College(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import College

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(College)
```

Now the Problem

I added channels to the INSTALLED_APPS list in the settings.py file like below,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'channelApp',
    'channels',
]
```

Now when I try to run the server using the runserver command I get the following error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'
>
> LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'.

I have been searching but failed to find any suitable answer. Kindly help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just after I posted this I stumbled onto a SO post

[Issue after installing django channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47019751/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-win32api-right-after-i-install-channels)

Just to reiterate in short, this is an open bug and the work around is to install the following package

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

After installing you may have to close and reopen the editor for the changes to reflect. And the error is resolved.

Comment: You probably should mark this as answered so that it shows in that status for others.

Comment: Yes I know, but SO only lets me do it after 2 days.