# extracting an excel file from html in python

Tags: python, vba, python-3.x, excel

I would like to open and copy an excel file (.xls) from a website in python.

I have the following code below:

```
import requests 

page = requests.get("https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/IC4WSA")

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
print(link.get('href'))
```

I have located string characters representing the href link to the excel file in the print line.

I would like to be able to open the excel workbook associated with the href and transfer the contents of the excel workbook to another excel workbook.  If possible I might also like to run a VBA macro to affect the updated excel workbook.

My question: how do I select and open the excel file using python and once open tranfer the data to another workbook or run a vba subroutine to create a final product?  Overall I am trying to build a simple and effective scraper of excel files with python.  If there are other structures or logical approaches I am interested to hear of those too.

Thanks!

Comment: `Workbooks.Open(urlToYourWorkbookHere)`

Comment: You can COM connect to Excel object library (like VBA does) using Python's `win32com` module if using Python on PC machine. To piggyback @TimWilliams comment: `import win32com; excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application"); doc = excel.Workbooks.Open( urlToYourWorkbookHere)`

Comment: what is the best library to get for this task?...i've downloaded two versions of the pywin32 package and loaded them...both are returning an error:    import win32api, sys, os
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am operating windows 7

Comment: Do you have Excel installed?  If Yes, 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: it is Excel 2003 so it is 32 bit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343774/importerror-no-module-named-win32api