# Python : ImportError: No module named 'win32types'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32, win32com

I try to use win32com to open word docs from python (3.5)
I installed pywin32, pypiwin32, win32com and som others...
I lauched > python pywin32_postinstall.py -install
Nothing to do.
When trying to launch makepy.py I always have the error

```
> python makepy.py
Generating to [...]\AppData\Local\Temp\pywin32\gen_py\00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x8x5.py
Building definitions from type library...
Generating...
Importing module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "makepy.py", line 443, in <module>
    rc = main()
  File "makepy.py", line 436, in main
    bBuildHidden=hiddenSpec)
  File "makepy.py", line 329, in GenerateFromTypeLibSpec
    info.minor)
  File "[...]\Python35\lib\site-packages\win32\com\client\gencache.py", line 653, in AddModuleToCache
    mod = _GetModule(fname)
  File "[...]\Python35\lib\site-packages\win32\com\client\gencache.py", line 735, in _GetModule
    mod = __import__(mod_name)
  File "[...]\AppData\Local\Temp\pywin32\gen_py\00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x8x5.py", line 10, in <module>
    import win32.com.client.CLSIDToClass, win32.com, win32types
ImportError: No module named 'win32types'
```

Comment: Possible dup of similar [ImportError: no module named win32api](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21343774/364696); did you by any chance install it with an IDE already running? Close it and reopen it after the install.

Comment: I think that solution is so simple that there is not that module at all. There is pywintypes module.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I tested that, not working.

Comment: Where did you find that module? There is nothing about it on google or I can't use google.

Comment: @N00b The `pywintypes` module lives in `Lib\site-packages\win32`

Comment: @BoarGules Yes i know but where is that win32types?

Comment: But is there that win32types module at all? Is that module something that exist only Jice's mind.

Comment: @ShadowRanger : no IDE running (all this was done in a command line). I just don't understand why i have this error (in fact, i also have it when i run the postinstall script)