# How to hide a running console with Python code

Tags: python, cmd, hide

I have a Python program that I compiled into an exe. When you start it, the console opens and the code runs, the user does not need anything, the code works by itself and performs its task. But I need to make the code continue to work, but the console is not visible to the user, how can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide console window in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764631/how-to-hide-console-window-in-python)

Comment: I have already found the answer to the question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54931392/python-hide-console-window/54932907](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54931392/python-hide-console-window/54932907)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python hide console window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54931392/python-hide-console-window)