# errors in jupyter kernel?

Tags: kernel, jupyter

I am new to the use of Jupiter and have set up a kernel, but an error is preventing anything happening. Any help would be appreciated. The text below is the error coming once I click on kernel error.

#### Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Users\DaraghOB\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1699, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "C:\Users\DaraghOB\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\DaraghOB\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 72, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "C:\Users\DaraghOB\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\DaraghOB\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\DaraghOB\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\DaraghOB\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\DaraghOB\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\DaraghOB\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\DaraghOB\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\DaraghOB\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Users\DaraghOB\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DaraghOB\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DaraghOB\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
    self.write_connection_file()
  File "C:\Users\DaraghOB\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 547, in write_connection_file
    kernel_name=self.kernel_name
  File "C:\Users\DaraghOB\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 212, in write_connection_file
    with secure_write(fname) as f:
  File "C:\Users\DaraghOB\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\DaraghOB\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 100, in secure_write
    win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
  File "C:\Users\DaraghOB\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 53, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
    import win32api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'
```

Error:

```
[W 15:52:50.140 NotebookApp] Unhandled error
[E 15:52:50.142 NotebookApp] {
      "Host": "localhost:8888",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Content-Length": "155",
      "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
      "Origin": "http://localhost:8888",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      "X-Xsrftoken": "2|84554945|64e97b7f58cd75b21096475070d1a2e9|1569407212",
      "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Desktop/masters/t81_558_deep_learning-master/t81_558_class_01_1_overview.ipynb",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
      "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
      "Cookie": "_xsrf=2|84554945|64e97b7f58cd75b21096475070d1a2e9|1569407212; username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1569423144|23:username-localhost-8888|44:MjM0NTcxYWViNDUwNGViZThiMmY3YzFkYjE0MGQ1YTg=|f6d09380ecff8b1434047c32ae8ad6aad5e82a616aec7b239665c023fb51d577\""
    }
[E 15:52:50.142 NotebookApp] 500 POST /api/sessions (::1) 77.96ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Desktop/masters/t81_558_deep_learning-master/t81_558_class_01_1_overview.ipynb`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: no module named win32api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343774/importerror-no-module-named-win32api)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I have tried to reinstall the `pywin32` package with pip but it did not work either

```
pip install pywin32
```

What solved my issue was to install it with `conda`

```
conda install pywin32
```

The version of the package is the same (227), but conda does something that pip does not.