# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named win32com Python 3.11

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

After reading and trying resolutions/suggestions posted in this and other forums, the problem still exist. Since I'm accessing corporate account in Outlook, is there any configuration/settings that needs to be done?

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'**

Package                Version

---

mysql-connector-python 8.0.32

---

pip                    23.1

---

pywin32                306

---

Python 3.11.2

Environment variable pointed to the directory where pywin32 is located

IDE is VS Code

Comment: Have you tried running the post install script? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48506623/14536215

Comment: Please provide more details. What did you try to do? [\[SO\]: ImportError: No module named win32com.client (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75310161/4788546), [\[SO\]: PyCharm doesn't recognize installed module (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73363599/4788546).

Comment: @Tzane initially got error of no such file.  managed to find the postinstall.py and copied to the Scripts folder but still same no such file error.             

python: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\.....\\pywin32_postinstall.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory   ; 
postinstall file here in this folder: C:\Users\.....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts