# I am trying to run scrapy crawl and getting this error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, scrapy, pyspider

I am trying to run scrapy crawl command in python 3.6 and getting this error 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'

I tried to use pip install win32api 
It says "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement win32api (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for win32api"

Any help ?
P.s: I am new to python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580855/where-to-find-the-win32api-module-for-python

Comment: Thank you @Wyrmwood it just solved my problem :)