# Reading Windows File Properties in Python

Tags: python, file

I am currently trying to write a script to find out, whether a file in a "company cloud" is available locally or not. I tried `path.isfile()`. The problem is: The files which are not available locally can still be accessed by `path.isfile()`. Then, the server automatically initiates a download of the file to make it available locally. For my application, this is unwanted behaviour.
So my next idea is the following:
I searched for file properties which makes locally available files and "cloud" files distinguishable. I seem to have found such a property:
The following pictures show the attributes O or N. How can I access these attributes in my python script? [File1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrmwu.png) [File2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5LVs.png)

Comment: Try to execute the command `attrib file_path` and see if you are getting the expected result.

Comment: Hi Abdul, unfortunately this did not do the trick. But thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580924/how-to-access-a-files-properties-on-windows) might be a useful place to look. The answers use the [`pyWin32`](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) module which you can install with `pip install pywin32`. Some of the answers use the `win32api` module which is what [`pyWin32` used to be called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580855/where-to-find-the-win32api-module-for-python).

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the mentioned question is limited to file versions. I can't really deduce a solution for finding my necessary attributes from this thread.